# Updating slides from sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to update slides from sheet. As simple as that.

1. I have a working script in sheet which updates the slide if I run it from the gscript editor
2. I want this script to run `onEdit` of specific cell in spreadsheet
3. So I add function

   ```
   function onEdit(e) {
     if ([e.range is what I want]){
       [update the slide using Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate]
   }
   ```
4. Upon changing the cell, I can see in my G Suite developer HUB an error message *Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project._)*

I am very new in this environment and I only wanted to achieve something simple. What am I missing? Do I really need to register new OAuth2 client app in google cloud platform to connect one google product to another?

Answer (score 1):

I figured the answer finally:

1. `onEdit`, as a simple trigger can't access advanced services (like slides)
2. Turns out I don't need advanced services at all, I only need a drawing on a sheet to trigger script and `UrlFetchApp` call with proper OAuth authentication, like that:

```
    var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(requests),
      'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
    };
```